# No module recognised after creating new virtualenv

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, modulenotfounderror

So, i have python 3.11 installed, i wanted to run a code with flask module, and it was running using original python, but not in vscode, so i followed a suggestion from stack exchange and used command python -m venv env.
This created a new folder called env, and after that i got a prompt that new virtual environment has been created, do you want to  use it for the workspace folder, i said yes, and still nothing worked.  And now even other modules are not being recognized either by vscode or the original python.exe.
I am a novice in programming and have no idea what to do, please help.
Thanks

Comment: Have you installed [conda](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html)?

Comment: Yeah i have installed conda

Answer (score 1):

Once a venv is created, you must activate it like so: `C:\User\venv_folder\Scripts\ activate`

If this doesn't work try using `C:\User\venv_folder\Scripts\ activate.ps1` or `activate.bat`

You'll know if it works once you have the `(venv_name)` before your command line in the terminal

Comment: Thanks, this didn't work but i did something, tbf a lot of different things, and something worked.

Answer (score 0):

> python -m venv env

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#how-venvs-work). Running this command creates the target directory (creating any parent directories that don’t exist already) and places a pyvenv.cfg file in it with a home key pointing to the Python installation from which the command was run (a common name for the target directory is .venv). It also creates a bin (or Scripts on Windows) subdirectory containing a copy/symlink of the Python binary/binaries (as appropriate for the platform or arguments used at environment creation time). It also creates an (initially empty) lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages subdirectory (on Windows, this is Lib\site-packages). If an existing directory is specified, it will be re-used.

I think what you need more is to create a conda environment. Use the following command to create it (take python 3.10.4 as an example), and then you can manually select it in python interpreter.

```
conda create -n env-01 python=3.10.4
```

[image]

You can also read [vscode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) for more details.